# UIScrollView with multipe TextViews and ImageViews layout issue

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview, autolayout, ios8

I have a view in which I placed a scrollView that fits the entire view. Inside the scrollView I have a textView, below a imageView, below a textView and so on. The textViews are filled with content from the ViewController with localized text, so its height will change depending on language. I gave the textViews the constraints for top, bottom, left and right with 10 each. The ImageViews i gave the constraints top and bottom with 10 each, width 200 and centered in container horizontal. The height of the images is different for each image and no constraint for the height is given.

[image]

The first result was, the scrollView got a width of the longest text of the localized text. I changed for the

1. scrollView

   - Content Hugging Priority Horizontal to 995 and Vertical to 250.
2. textViews

   - Content Hugging Priority Horizontal of 400 and 200 Vertical,
   - Content Compression Resistance Priority Horizontal is 200 and Vertical 750.

Perfect result in portrait mode. When changing to landscape the width of the scrollView stays at 320 and is aligned to the left.

How can I fix the problem to let the scrollView take 100% width of the screen without giving the textViews the chance to force to enlarge themselves to 100% width?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

The scrollView has constraints: top/bottom 8 and left/right 0 each to superview.

The textViews have constraints to top, left, bottom and right.

The images have constraints top, bottom and width, centered to X in container.

This results that the textViews take one line and grow to giant width.

Then I centered the textViews to X in Container and selected all textViews and images and centered them too.

Now the scrollView takes 100% width of screen, height as needed no matter if portrait or landscape.

So for all who have maybe the same issue: scrollView looks a bit smaller than the view, its constraints when adding are 0 to left and right and a top/bottom >0. When drag and drop scrollView in the view it takes 100% of the view size. That was the problem, the constraints were -16. Setting the scrollView to x = 16 and width = 288 results in fitting properly to the view! Next giving the textViews constraints top/left/bottom/right and center it to container (even if offset to real center, right to the item is 0 predefined - change it to use current canvas value).